# Error [RuntimeException] Could not scan for classes inside "database/seeds"

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I have a problem running composer update

the same thing happens with other installation commands too

Error:

> [RuntimeException]   Could not scan for classes inside
> "database/seeds" which does not appear to be a file nor a folder

How can I solve this error? try, running composer install and it doesn't work either

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"type": "project",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": [
    "framework",
    "laravel"
],
"license": "MIT",
"require": {
    "php": "^7.2.5",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.2",
    "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^1.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
    "laravel/framework": "^7.0",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
    "laravel/ui": "^2.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "facade/ignition": "^2.0",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.9.1",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.3.1",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "^4.1",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.5"
},
"config": {
    "optimize-autoloader": true,
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true
},
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "dont-discover": []
    }
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories"
    ]
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true,
"scripts": {
    "post-autoload-dump": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
        "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
    ],
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
    ]
}
}
```

Comment: try putting `seeds` and `factories` folder in databases folder if not there also class `DatabaseSeeder` may not present there

Comment: seeders and factories folders are in database

Comment: and  what about class `DatabaseSeeder` ?

Comment: What's your question about this? Do the folders `database/seeds`  and `database/factories`  exist?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change composer autoload to

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    }
```

In Laravel 8 two directories Factory and seeders have Namespace. While in Laravel 7 it's still using the class-map to load them.

First, check your classes if they are using namespace then use psr4 autoload otherwise you can use class-map;

Answer (score 2):

In my case I changed `"database/seeds"` to `"database/seeders"` under `composer.json > autoload > classmap` and SOLVED the issue.

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "classmap": [
        "database/seeders",
        "database/factories"
    ]
},
```

Comment: Solution still works in Laravel 10.